# Find the sum, the sum of the squares, and the sum of the cubes for the first $250$ natural numbers.

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

The answers are:

1. $784,375$
2. $\frac{250(251)(501)}{6} = 5,239,625$
3. $\frac{250^2(251)^2}{4} = 984,390,625$

How is the first answer $784,375? $ The answer I get is $31,375$.

Comment: More pertinently, why do you say that the answer to the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $250$ is $784,375$ when that is manifestly far too large?

Comment: He/she did not obtain that answer, the answer provided, I believe is incorrect.

Comment: 784,375 is the given answer. Any chance we are misinterpreting the question?

Comment: What is the *exact* question?

Comment: "Find the sum, the sum of the squares, and the sum of the cubes for the first 250 natural numbers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of an AP consisting of $n$ terms is given by

$\dfrac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$

Here, 
the sum of natural numbers till 250 is $\dfrac{250(251)}{2}= 31375$

Hence, your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Why would you believe your answer is incorrect if you know your did the work correctly?

The first $250$ natural numbers are $1-250$.

Finding the average of $1$ and $250$, you get $125.5$

Since the average is $125.5$, you multiply $125.5$ by $250$, since you are accounting for the first $250$ natural numbers.

$125.5*250=31,375$

The answer provided ($784,375$) is incorrect.

Comment: Note the average of the largest and smallest numbers in a set if numbers is not necessarily the average of **all** of the numbers.  If the numbers are an arithmetic sequence, as is the case here, then that is correct.  Yolo Inver gives a very quick and nice answer.

Comment: @user247327 Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I guess this was downvoted, since it was not a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write the first 250 natural numbers as

1    2    3    4    5  ...  248   249   250  and below then write

250 249  248 247  246  ...    3     2     1

Adding each pair **vertically** gives 251 for each pair.  There are 250 pairs so the total is (250)(251)= 62750.  But each number from 1 to 250 has been added **twice**.  The sum of the first 250 natural numbers is half of that: 62750/2= 31375.  Where did you get "748375"?